# How to pass a json object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have this code, I created an object "person" and in the method "DoJson" I declare the person and return it, I saw examples on internet and I do the same but it does not work.

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   [WebMethod]
   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]//Specify return format.
   public string DoJson()
   {
        var pers = new Person();
        pers.edad = 1;
        pers.nombre = "Name";

        return pers;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int edad;
    public string nombre;
}
```

Comment: `public string DoJson(){` ==> `public Person DoJson(){`

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you describe it along with any error codes or exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a conversion from object to json. See the [MSDN Docs on the converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) -

```
public string DoJson(){
    var pers = new Person();
    pers.edad = 1;
    pers.nombre = "Name";
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
            new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    return  oSerializer.Serialize(pers);
}
```

You may need to add a reference to `System.Web` dll if one does not already exist.

Comment: `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` is to inform WebService to convert the response object to json before sending to client. So no need for a double serialization..

Answer (score 0):

change it to this

```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
    public Person GetData(string id)
    {
        // lookup person with the requested id 
        return new Person()
                   {
                       edad= Convert.ToInt32(edad), 
                       nombre = "Leo Messi"
                   };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case i think you just need to change the return type of the method DoJson() (at the moment you are returning an object as a string)

Change:

```
public string DoJson()
```

To:

```
public Person DoJson()
```

Then of course, return a person.

This is because the serializer needs to know that it is a person and then start to serialize.

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood your needs. But also with a webservice it is possible to use the newtonsoft serializer. My personal opinion is that it works a lot better.